# why it appears error when I convert the value which I take it from EditText to integer

Tags: java, android

why when I convert from String to int it appears error, but I think the convert is right. but I do nat know what is the error
this is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText weight;
    EditText age;
    Button result;
    TextView txtresult;

    String w;
    String a;
    double  r1;
    int w1;
    int a1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        weight=findViewById(R.id.w);
        age=findViewById(R.id.a);
        result=findViewById(R.id.btnresult);
        txtresult=findViewById(R.id.txtresult);

        w= weight.getText().toString();
        w1=Integer.parseInt(w);


        a= age.getText().toString();
        a1=Integer.parseInt(a);

        r1=w1/2.2*a1/28.3/8;
        result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtresult.setText("number of cups :"+r1);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

the error message:

```
03-12 11:33:43.997 2469-2469/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2334155 that was originally bound here
                                                 android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2334155 that was originally bound here
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                                                     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
                                                     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
                                                     at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
                                                     at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-12 11:33:43.997 2469-2469/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2334155 that was originally bound here
                                                 android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@2334155 that was originally bound here
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
                                                     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
                                                     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
                                                     at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
                                                     at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
                                                     at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: This error is not related to your app.

Comment: Yes as @Henry says this is not related to your app. Depending on how you are looking at logs, (Android Studio / command line) there are ways to filter logs to just your application. I suggest you research these.

Comment: The error message basically means that some component created a binding to a Service and did not unbind from the service before the component was destroyed.